# How to compute a property based on an object with fallback

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, reactive-programming

I have a component that receives an object as prop, like this:

```
props: ['propObject']
```

Then, there's a default object defined (I use VueX, so it's actually defined as a `$store` getter, but to make it simpler, let's say it's defined in the data method) in the data:

```
data() {
  return {
    dataObject: {defaultValueA: 1, defaultValueB: 2}
  }
}
```

And I'd like to have a computed property that would behavior like this:

```
computed: {
  computedObject() {
    return Object.values(this.propObject).length > 0 ? this.propObject : this.dataObject;
  }
}
```

However, I know this is not possible because Vue watchers don't watch for changes in the key/value pairs of an object.
I have tried to go with a watched property, like this:

```
props: ['propObject'],
data() {
  return {
    object: {},
    defaultObject: {}
  }
},
watch: {
  propObject: {
    handler: function() {
      this.setComputedObject();
    },
    deep: true
  }
},
methods: {
  setComputedObject() {
    this.object =  Object.values(this.propObject).length > 0 ? this.propObject : this.defaultObject;
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.setComputedObject();
}
```

However, the watcher handler is not being called at all when the `propObject` changes, but if I call it directly via console, it works. Is there any way that I can make the `computedObject` become reactive?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `Vue.set`/`vm.$set` where you change the props (in source component)

for example

```
changeProp(){
this.$set(propObject,'newprop','newval');
}
```

and then just you regualr compouted in the target component (the component which receive the prop)

source : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: This actually worked, thank you so much. But, what if the property on the parent/source component is a computed property? In my case, it was a `v-model="customizations['keyA']"`. Is there a way to make this v-model object reactive?

Comment: not fully understand what you mean. example of code will help. anyway the v-model is just sugar text for `@input` and `:value` in most of the elements (some elments use diff events and attrbs). you can always take the full control with the correct events and attrbs. take a look here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components for how v-model works.